# app:visibleGone cannot resolve on android Databinding

Tags: android, mvvm, android-databinding

When I build the project. I'm getting error on app:visibleGone

I'm also enable true to dataBinding in build.gradle and using android architecture components and mvvm.
project `targetSdkVersion` is  `26` and `support lib version is 26.0.1`.

Below is the error message

[image]

```
error: package com.****.****.databinding does not exist
error: cannot find symbol class ActivityMainBinding
Cannot find the setter for attribute 'app:visibleGone' with parameter type boolean on android.widget.Button.
```

here is my ***activity_main.xml***

```
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="loading"
            type="boolean" />

    </data>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.example.aungmyolwin.importdb.MainActivity">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_load_sql"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Load from SQL"
            app:visibleGone="@{!loading}"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_load_room"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Load from Room mapper"
            app:visibleGone="@{!loading}"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_import_loading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Importing database...."
            app:visibleGone="@{loading}"/>


    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

***ActivityMain.java***

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

        binding.btnLoadRoom.setOnClickListener(this);
        binding.btnLoadSql.setOnClickListener(this);

        viewModels= ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainActivityViewModels.class);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to create a custom `BindingAdapter` for `app:visibleGone` (because it is not a available method).
Like

```
public class BindingAdapters {
    @BindingAdapter("visibleGone")
    public static void showHide(View view, boolean show) {
        view.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Moreover, if you don't want to define a method like this, you can do like

```
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="loading"
            type="boolean" />
        <import type="android.view.View"/> <!-- remember to import -->
    </data>

    <LinearLayout >
        <Button
            android:visibility="@{loading ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}"
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```